# MVC Net Core with Docker Containers Benefits

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-core-2.0

I am creating a simple MVC Net Core app with C# backend, and ASP CSS/html/Razor front end. It is a simple start project where customers can create orders, buy books, and place into a shopping cart.  How would Docker images support this? Or would this be an overkill for MVC.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question - can you clarify? Docker images are an abstraction layer between your host machine and your application. We're running our ASP.NET Core API in docker and hosting it on Kubernetes - we'are also using load balancing and autoscaling with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not overkill. It's actually quite simple and the dockerization brings a lot of advantages. Read for example the .Net Core dockerization page on Docker docs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/dotnetcore/

Some of the advantages are:

- Portability: You can take a known to work image and put it in another environment (dev/testing/staging/production)
- Isolation from the host system
- Scalability: Take the app container to a cloud provider and run instances based on load

You have to think about persistance: You shouldn't store data in the docker container because this can easily be lost when removing the container. Usually you start a database container next to your app container and store it's data in a volume or on the host filesystem.