# MVC Net Core with Docker Containers Problems

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am creating a simple MVC Net Core app with C# backend, and ASP CSS/html/Razor front end. It is a simple start project where customers can create orders, buy books, and place into a shopping cart. Previous question discussed the benefits. However, what problems or limitations would have if introducing Docker in the workplace? Anything I need to tell manager before incorporating into a corporate setting for simple application? I read Docker contains may have issues with security settings or talking with other micro service apps.

Prior Question:

[MVC Net Core with Docker Containers Benefits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55757748/mvc-net-core-with-docker-containers-benefits)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest googling for success stories. For example https://apiumhub.com/tech-blog-barcelona/top-benefits-using-docker/

Security is not such a big issue. Your software needs to be as secure as it needs to be when running on the host directly plus you get some level of resource isolation (memory, filesystem, etc.). This doesn't free you from writing secure code in the first place, but is an additional advantage.

Container to container networking on the same host is quite easy as docker provides the addresses of other containers as environment variables. On a larger scale with multiple servers you need to think about service discovery and maybe load balancing.

But start small and try it on your local machine, start dockerizing your app and use docker images to test your software. When that is established, you can try to move it into production. Also here you can start with a smaller microservice and get some experience in production before trying to migrate a huge mission-critical software in a big bang scenario.